# Beautiful Soup Parse Multiple Tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm working with the data for my school grading system and I'm trying to figure out how to extract the data by category.

This is the raw HTML:https://pastebin.com/icbaemd7

Right now, I've written a Python script:

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

chemData = ((soup.find_all('td')))
content = []
print chemData
print ""
for i in chemData:
    content.append(i.getText().split('</td')[0])
for k in content:
    print (k)
```

Which returns this result:

```
Safety Contract Signed
1/1
8/13/2019

Student Profile Sheet Turned In
1/1
8/13/2019

Polyatomic Ion Quiz
10/10
8/19/2019

HW Quiz Ch. 3 Target 6
3/3
8/27/2019

HW Quiz (Ch. 3 Targets 1-6)
12/16
8/28/2019

Chapters 1 & 2 Formative Quiz
15/17
8/21/2019

Chapter 3 Formative Quiz
23.5/25
9/5/2019

Lab Report: Antifreeze Lab
10/10
8/21/2019

Types of Reactions Lab Report
11/12
8/23/2019

Hydrate Lab Report
10/10
8/29/2019

Lab Assessment - Types of Reactions Lab
10/15
8/26/2019

Lab Assessment: Hydrate Lab
10/10
9/3/2019
```

However I want to sort these into the categories as present in the HTML. If I run the same script with `h3` instead of `td`, I get them:

```
Homework
Formative Quizzes
Lab Reports
Lab Assessments
```

So my question is: How do I get it to automatically sort the actual assignments into the respective categories?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your html does not renders properly. However as quick solution, look for the parent container that holds both the h3 tag and the table for each category and **scrape** the parent container first. For example, let us assume that the h3 tag and the table are under a div. Then first **scrape** the div tag ie d = soup.findall('div'). Then loop through the d further to extract the h3 tag and then the tr/td. Ex. d[0].findall('h3') d[0].findall('td') and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following where you test if h3 and make dictionary key otherwise add in values from row under that current dict[key]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''yourHTML'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
results = {}

for i in soup.select('h3, tr'):
    if i.name == 'h3':
        header = i.text
        results[header] = []
    else:
        results[header].append(' '.join([n.text for n in i.select('td')]))
print(results)
```